# Get last location is not working when location services are enabled through the dialog box

Tags: android, google-maps

If I start the activity with location services enabled, the app is able to retrieve my last location coordinates. However, if the activity is started without location services enabled and I click on my get current location button, I am shown a dialog box which allows me to enable location services. Once it's enabled, I'm still not able to retrieve my last location coordinates - I am returned with "Current location is null" as per the Toast in my code. I've seen other threads but the solutions seem too intrusive to my existing code. I'm pretty hopeful a minor tweak in my existing code will resolve my issue.

```
public class ExploreFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mapView;
    private Location currentLocation;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
    private String apiKey = "[KEY REMOVED]";
    private PlacesClient placesClient;
    private LatLng userLocation;
    FloatingActionButton buttonCurrentLocation;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explore, null, false);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lastLocation();

        buttonCurrentLocation = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonCurrentLocation);
        buttonCurrentLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    locationDialog();
                } else {
                    if (currentLocation != null) {
                        userLocation = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
                        mapView.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 15.0f));
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Current location is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mapView = googleMap;

        if (currentLocation != null) {
            userLocation = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
            mapView.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 15.0f));
        }
    }

    private void locationDialog() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setTitle("No GPS signal found")  // GPS not found
                .setMessage("To continue, turn on device location") // Want to enable?
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No, thanks", null)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    lastLocation();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void lastLocation() {
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getContext());
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]
                    {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(ExploreFragment.this);
                if (location != null) {
                    currentLocation = location;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location object may be `null` in the following situations:

- Location is turned off in the device settings. The result could be null even if the last location was previously retrieved because disabling location also clears the cache.
- The device never recorded its location, which could be the case of a new device or a device that has been restored to factory settings.
- Google Play services on the device has restarted, and there is no active Fused Location Provider client that has requested location after the services restarted. To avoid this situation you can create a new client and request location updates yourself. For more information, see Receiving Location Updates.

It seems like you catch third situation :)

More about it in [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current)